# Zero-way binding HTML Templates with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsrender

This may be a newb question, but my problem scope is this:

- I'm rewriting server-side HTML templates into client-side HTML
  templates
- I've got tens of thousands of lines of jQuery-based HTML manipulation
  JavaScript which I simply can't rewrite yet
- I've already got Angular on the client-side, so I want to use that,
  NOT JsRender to "zero-way" bind (as opposed to one-way and two-way
  binding) the JSON data to the templates to get raw, manipulable HTML

Once the HTML is generated, I need to "unhook" or scrub the Angular binding to let me fully manipulate the divs, table rows, text inputs, etc -- i.e. reorder them, remove them, edit them -- without Angular freaking out and trying to rewrite the HTML to match the JSON again.

Basically, I need the frowny face...

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

... and someday soon I'll have the team and the bandwidth to rewrite the old jQuery-only JS into Angular-based JS -- the smiley face.  And I'm reaaaally hoping to not have to re-re-write the datamodels and the templates (other than topical changes like "onClick >> ng-click").

Is "zero-way" binding possible with AngularJS?  If not, I need to add yet another JS library to this already JS-laden app.

Thank you.

P.S. I'm working on a JSFiddle with the concept of: "for all DOM elements >> jquery(this).unbind()" -- but it's gonna be slow.  And bad.  And might not even work.  And probably totally the wrong direction to go.

Anyway, your insights would be invaluable.  Thank you again.

Comment: Any possibility of detaching the whole element and swap and then compile the new HTML again?

Comment: Might work, but then I'd have to re-load the entire JSON doc after every change, big or small.  Also it doesn't address what it'd do during the edits (before changes are saved) and old-school JQuery Table sorting and whatnot...

Comment: write a directive that do same as ng-non-bindable, but $compile elem.contents() manually once by putting a flag in attribute or somewhere.